# Keep the list menu on one line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu looking like this:

[image: Example]

but for some reason my menu looks like this:

[image: problem]

As you can see, I am trying to keep the 2nd row of menu options in one line but whatever I try to do it doesn't seem to do that.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/header/seal.jpg" alt="" style="width:106px;height:67px;"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="nav_box">
            <ul id="mini_nav">
                <li><a href="#">Voorwaarden</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Olivetti</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Producten</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}

/* - 2.5 - MENU
------------------------------------------ */

#logo {
    margin-left:45px;
    margin-top:18px;
    float:left;
}

#header {
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; height:112px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
}

#nav_box {
    float:right;
    margin-right:50px;
    margin-top:25px;
}

#mini_nav li {
    font-family:'Myriad Pro';
    float:right;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #bbbbbb;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left:22px;
}

#mini_nav li a{
    font-family:'Myriad Pro';
    color: #bbbbbb;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#nav li {
    font-family:'Oxygen';
    float:right;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #bbbbbb;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-left:22px;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#nav li a{
    font-family:'Oxygen';
    color: #bbbbbb;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

I am kind of lost on how to tackle, maybe you guys could help me out on this?
I have tried using the position property and the float property but it doesn't seem to work. I'm probably thinking to hard on this.

Comment: give your `#nav_box` a width that will allow your links to fit onto one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying:

```
.mini_nav {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

or

```
.mini_nav:after {
   content: ".";
   height: 0;
   visibility: none;
   display: block;
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Your second suggestion fixed the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid using `float` for this task and use `display: inline-block;` instead:

```
#mini_nav li {
    font-family:'Myriad Pro';
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #bbbbbb;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left:22px;
}
```

When you use `float` you take elements out of the document flow and can get into all kinds of layout issues. Using `display: inline-block` keeps the elements in the document flow.

[Here is a mock-up of your HTML and CSS with this change](http://jsfiddle.net/DYzUE/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear div between both . That is you need to add  between both

```
<ul>....First list....</ul>
```

`<div class="clear"></div>`

`<ul>....second list....</ul>`

"clear" class will have following css

```
.clear {
  clear:both
}
```

[here is a demo](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/yxqIt)